# OpenCL Verification of Parallel Execution

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, opencl, gpgpu

**What methods exist to verify that work is indeed being parallelized by OpenCL? (How can I verify that work is being distributed to all the processing elements for execution?) Or at least a method to monitor which cores/processors of the GPU or CPU are being used?**

I would simply like a way to verify that OpenCL is actually doing what its specification claims it is supposedly doing. To do this, I need to collect hard evidence that OpenCL / the OS / the drivers are indeed scheduling kernels and work items to be executed in parallel (as opposed to serially).

I have written an OpenCL program conforming to the OpenCL API 1.2 specification along with a simple OpenCL C kernel which simply squares in the input integer.

In my program, `work_group_size = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` (so that they will fit on the compute units and so that OpenCL won't throw a fit).

The total `amount_of_work` is a scalar multiple of (`MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS * MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`). Since `amount_of_work > MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS * MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, hopefully OpenCL

Hopefully this would be enough to force the schedulers to execute the maximum number of kernels + work items efficiently as possible, making use of the available cores / processors.

- For a CPU, you can check `cpuid`, or `sched_getcpu`, or `GetProcessorNumber` in order to check which core / processor the current thread is currently executing on.
- Is there a method on the OpenCL API which provides this information? (I have yet to find any.)
- Is there an OpenCL C language built in function... or perhaps do the vendor's compilers understand some form of assembly language which I could use to obtain this information?
- Is there an equivalent to `cpuid`, `sched_getcpu`, or `GetProcessorNumber` for GPUs for core usage monitoring, etc? Perhaps something vender architecture specific?
- Is there an external program which I could use as a monitor for this information? I have tried Process Monitor and AMD's CodeXL, both of which are not useful for what I'm looking for. Intel has VTune, but I doubt that works on an AMD GPU.
- Perhaps I could take a look at the compiled kernel code as generated from the AMD and Intel Compilers for some hints?

**Hardware Details**:

- GPU: AMD FirePro, using AMD Capeverde architecture, 7700M Series chipset. I don't know which one exactly of in the series it is. If there is an AMD instruction set manual for this architecture (i.e. there are manuals for x86), that would possibly be a start.
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz

**Development Environment Details**:

- OS: Win 7 64-bit, will also eventually need to run on Linux, but that's besides the point.
- Compiling with MinGW `GNU GCC 4.8.1 -std=c++11`
- Intel OpenCL SDK (OpenCL header, libraries, and runtime)
- According to Process Manager, Intel's OpenCL compiler is a clang variant.
- AMD APP OpenCL SDK (OpenCL header, libraries, and runtime)
- OpenCL 1.2
- I am trying to keep the source code as portable as possible.

Comment: Simple test is via workload, compare single vs 2 threads

Comment: @kchoi Can you expand a bit on that? Perhaps in an OpenCL context, that would mean `work_group_size = 1` vs `work_group_size = MAX`?

Comment: This abstraction on how the code is executed is what OpenCL specs tryes to do. Why would you like to know how it is being executed internally? Even if you knew, you CAN'T change it. And even if the kernel is not using 100% of the available resources, you never know what is being used in the rest of cores. (other applications, screen refresh, etc...). You have to assume the driver will do it's best to fit the order in the device.

Comment: @DarkZeros Why: I want to verify the parallelism (if there is indeed any), and if there is, to what degree. It would also be good to know if the kernel or drivers are limiting how much of a device OpenCL can access, and to what degree they are "interfering", so to speak.

Comment: I'm afraid you will not find any tools for this inside the OpenCL spec. Since the aim is just the oposite, provide a generic enviroment that abstracts the underlying HW. Maybe you can find something into the driver manufacturer. But I really doubt they will provide anything more detailed than "GPU usage %".

Comment: @wazzy, I share your frustration. How do I set global_work_size at run time to maximize performance? I have resorted to a running a short pre-run benchmark with values 1,2,4,8,16,32,... Once global_work_size is determined, another benchmark run determines how much work to give to each kernel invocation. For CPU, I set global_work_size from CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS.

Comment: @wazzy (continued) Here is an example of a benchmark used to set global_work_size. It is running on AMD HD 7850. The first column is n, where global_work_size = 1 << n. The second column is ns per kernel. The result shows that throughput scales with global_work_size for values through 4096. Apparently HD 7850 can execute 4096 copies of my loop in parallel.
`0 889667148
 1 441320146
 2 220689942
 3 110356153
 4  55184211
 5  27703757
 6  13853802
 7   6898669
 8   3422420
 9   1706541
10    855429
11    427780
12    213881
13    136127
14    123508
15    115031
16    110926
17    108865
`

Comment: Work items are always executed in parallel, by definition. How many at once depends on your hardware.

Comment: @ScottD I see, so you are using global_work_size to (hopefully) influence the number of compute units that get utilized by the GPU? This seems like a good, naive way to measure GPU usage. Naive because we still don't have full control over the scheduler, thus times would likely not be reproducible. The theoretical limit on max number of parallel computations would be `L = CL_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS*CL_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. The execution time for `global_work_size <= L` should be a constant. The execution time for `global_work_size > L` should increase linearly or in steps of `CL_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`

Comment: @user9111337 Yes, that's true. What we're interested in with this question is a method to measure how well OpenCL is utilizing the GPU. This is not just dependent on hardware. It's as DarkZeros states: The software (the drivers and schedulers) influences execution too. The hardware will only give you theoretical usage limits. Maybe the scheduler decides your application gets the lowest priority because it deems other tasks to be more important. Or perhaps somehow you've been able to dedicate the device to the task. The amount of parallelism would likely differ in those cases.

Comment: @DarkZeros I have thought about this for a while now. If there really were a way to influence this, there would be a method to set the number of `COMPUTE_UNITS` the computation would use in our code. The extent of our control is limited to within a given compute unit, meaning we are able to make changes resulting in 100% usage of a given compute unit (i.e. 100% "efficiency").

Comment: @wazzy: By the way, my gpu is dedicated to opencl. I set `local_work_size` to NULL and `work_dim` to 1 so that `the OpenCL implementation will determine how to be break the global work-items into appropriate work-group instances`. This simplifies tuning by leaving 'global_work_size' as the only variable. Your `L = CL_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS*CL_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` does indeed calculate the apparent max parallel execution for gpu devices. However, I need to double this value several times to avoid ~50% throughput loss. (more)...

Comment: (continued) For cpu, `L = CL_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS*CL_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` becomes 8192 on my Core i7-2600K, resulting in considerable performance loss. For this 4 core, 8 thread cpu, 8 or 16 works best (but even with `global_work_size` properly set to 8 or 16, a traditional hand-coded multi-threaded app gives 5X the performance of opencl). So even for my simple app running on a dedicated gpu, there is apparently no way to calculate an optimum value for `global_work_size`.

Comment: @wazzy keep in mind that `CL_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` is a highly theoretical value. Statements like `The execution time for global_work_size <= L should be a constant` may hold true for some hardware but definitely not for a GPU, since on a GPU you generally need multiple work groups for each compute unit to get max. utilization (while workgroup size only needs to be bigger than ~256). And just as a side note: `global_work_size` in a real application depends on the size of your input data and will usually be much bigger than `L`, otherwise you wouldn't be using OpenCL in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of relying on speculations, you can comment-out a program's buffer copies and visualisations, leave only kernel-executions intact. Then put it in a tight loop and watch for heat rising. If it heats like furmark, then it is using cores. If it is not heating, you can disable serial operations in kernels too(gid==0), then try again. For example, a simple nbody simulator pushes a well cooled HD7000 series gpu to over 70°C in minutes and 90°C for poor coolers. Compare it to a known benchmark's temperature limits.

Similar thing for CPU exists. Using float4 heats more than simple floats which shows even instruction type is important to use all ALUs (let alone threads)

If GPU has a really good cooler, you can watch its Vdroop. More load means more voltage drop. More cores more drop, more load per core also more drop.

Whatever you do, its up to compiler and hardware's abilities and you don't have explicit control over ALUs. Because opencl hides hardware complexity from developer.

Usin msi-after burner or similar software is not useful because they show %100 usage even when you use %1 of cards true potential.

Simply look at temperature difference of computer case at equilibrium state from starting state. If delta-T is like 50 with opencl and 5 without opencl, opencl is parallelising stuff you can't know how much.